# How to import data from csv to minishop2 product

Tags: csv, modx, modx-revolution

Who knows how to import data from a csv table to a product using minishop2(ModX Revo)? It has a script csv.php but I don't understand how to use it correctly to create a product. 
Can you please tell me how to get data from csv in stages and create a product using the existing html template.

P.S. I would also be grateful if you could advise on an alternative method of import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you can purchase this extra: https://en.modstore.pro/packages/import-and-export/msimportexport

Here are some helpful links(but you should use translator as Russian is there):

- https://modxguru.ru/blog/programming/import-csv-minishop2.html
- https://forums.modx.com/thread/103603/php-minishop2
- https://modx.pro/search?page=2&query=%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82+%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2